# Integration algorith faster in 32 bit system

Tags: c, virtual-machine, 32bit-64bit

I have short homework, where I need to analyze performance of virtual machines.
So I've installed xubuntu 13.10 64bit on host, and xubuntu 13.10 32 bit and 64 bit on virtualbox enviroment.
Also I wrote few tests. One is Integration with Simpson metod, and I wrote it as below:
[Code of integrating](http://pastebin.com/pFeVUTzg)

I compiled it with gcc and -O2 option and timed on these two virtual machines and host.
Results:
100 000 000 intervals and 100 cycles:
vbox32 - 11,02 sek
vbox64 - 53,01 sek
host   - 52,11 sek.

I reran this test few times and results are nearly the same. 
I wonder why this algorith is faster in 32 bit system, even if it's virtual machine ?

Ps. My computer specification:
- core i7 3gen
- 16 gb ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as You do not provide more than 4GB ram, you mostly will have lower performance on 64 bit than on 32 bit. Afaik this is due to stronger heap allocation, more oftwn heap allocation and some undefined processes with 8 byte pointer translation on  mem layout under 4 gb.